# Js barcode scan from webcam

Tags: javascript, webcam, barcode

I would like to scan barcode from my webcam but not image.

Is it possible ? How can i do ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long answer: Maximize the contrast of the image, saturate the image, triangulate the extremes of each bar in the barcode, calculate a plain projection of the barcode, measure the width of each bar, make them a percentage, translate with the appropriate reference table

Short answer, use a dedicated library like https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/